# How to replace literal strings in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have this code where I can't seem to backslash the find/replace strings correctly:

```
$find = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
$replace = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36"

Get-Content prefs.js | %{ $_ -replace  $find, $replace } | Set-Content prefs.js
```

The `$find` value isn't being replaced by the `$replace` value when this is run.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like you deal with literal strings. Do not use the `-replace` operator 
which deals with regular expressions. Use the `Replace` method:

```
... | %{$_.Replace("string to replace", "replacement")} | ...
```

Alternatively, if you still want to use `-replace` then also use `[regex]::Escape(<string>)`. It will do the escaping for you.

**Example: replacing text literally with "$_"**

Compare the results of the following, showing what can happen if you use an automatic variable in a regex replacement:

```
[PS]> "Hello" -replace 'll','$_'                  # Doesn't work!
HeHelloo

[PS]> "Hello".Replace('ll','$_')                  # WORKS!
He$_o
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem by using the method instead of the regex one!